# Scale variables over a moving date window in R: script works, but unacceptably slow. Ways to optimize? rstats

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, iteration, purrr

I have a data frame, where each rows represents data for a specific category on a specific day:

```
set.seed(1)
k <- 10
df <- data.frame(
    name = c(rep('a',k), rep('b',k)), 
    date = rep(seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'),as.Date('2017-01-01')+k-1, 'days'),2),
    x = runif(2*k,1,20),
    y = runif(2*k,100,300)
    )
View(df)
```

Head:

```
 head(df)
  name       date         x        y
1    a 2017-01-01  6.044665 286.9410
2    a 2017-01-02  8.070354 142.4285
3    a 2017-01-03 11.884214 230.3348
4    a 2017-01-04 18.255948 125.1110
5    a 2017-01-05  4.831957 153.4441
6    a 2017-01-06 18.069404 177.2228
```

Structure:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ name: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ date: Date, format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" ...
 $ x   : num  6.04 8.07 11.88 18.26 4.83 ...
 $ y   : num  287 142 230 125 153 ...
```

I need to scale x and y variables of this data over a specific date window.
The script I came up with is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df
moving_window_days <- 4

##Iterate over each row in df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ 
    df2[i,] <- df %>% 
        ##Give me only rows for 'name' on the current row 
        ##which are within the date window of interest
        filter(date <= date(df[i,"date"]) & 
               date >= date(df[i,"date"]) - moving_window_days & 
               name == df[i,"name"]
               ) %>% 
        ##Now scale x and y on this date wondow
        mutate(x = percent_rank(x), 
               y = percent_rank(y)
        ) %>% 
        ##Get rid of the rest of the rows - leave only the row we are looking at
        filter(date == date(df[i,"date"])) 
}
```

It works as intended *(well, I initially wanted to get each observation's percentile in a moving window, but scaled values will work just fine)*
The problem is that the real dataset is much larger:

- `'name'` column has 30 local branch offices
- `'date'` is at least a year worth of data for each branch
- instead of `'x'` and `'y'` I have 6 variables
- the moving window is 90 days

I ran this script on the real data, and out of **30,000 rows** it was able to go over only **5,000** in **4 hours**...
This is the first time I run into a problem like this.

I am sure my script is highly inefficient (I'm sure because I am not a pro in R. I am just assuming there is always a better way)

**Any way this script can be optimized / improved?**

- Any way to 'purrrify' (use some of the `map` functions in `purrr`)?
- Nested dataframe? `nest()`? Thinking this is a solution... Not sure how to implement...

**Anything I can do to perhaps tackle the problem in a different manner?**

Comment: This is more of a topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So you want to calculate the percentile for each observation, based on the current and four previous periods?

Comment: @Odysseus210 perhaps you're right, but R isn't much reviewed there... And I do know many R questions are answered here.

Comment: @Mako212 sort of. Either a percentile or scale it based on X previous days. 4 days in the sample code, 90 days in real data.

Comment: Are you running on a mac or windows? Or something else?

Comment: Also, with your code, I'm getting this error: `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: unused argument (df[i, "date"])`

Comment: Running on Windows. Let me check the script again. Sorry about that

Comment: @TarasK I got the same error as Odysseus. Consider trying `data.table`. Some googling found a similar solution for a window sum. I can't get it to work for your rank calculation yet, but it might get you going in the right direction. `weather[, rain_3 := Reduce("+", shift(rain, 0:2)), by = square]`

Comment: @Mako212 @Odysseus210 Yes, my bad! Forgot to attach `library(lubridate)`

Comment: @TarasK Does this look right? `require(zoo); require(data.table)`, `df2[, rank := rollapply(x,4,percent_rank)]`

Comment: Edit: nope, it looks close but not quite right

Comment: @TarasK: my answer below will take some study to understand, but I remember at work, reducing the run time of a program from a day and a half, down to 3 or 4 hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is parallel processing. I utilize the `future` package for this. This may annoy some poeple, who may consider it a hack, because the future package is intended... Well... For futures (or "promises" if you're a front end developer). This approach is finicky, but works very well.

```
    library(future)

    # Create a function that iterates over each row in the df:
    my_function <- function(df, x) {
          x <- df
      for(i in 1:nrow(df)){ 
          x[i, ] <- df %>% 
              ##Give me only rows for 'name' on the current row 
              ##which are within the date window of interest
              filter(date <= date(df[i,"date"]) & 
                     date >= date(df[i,"date"]) - moving_window_days & 
                     name == df[i,"name"]
                     ) %>% 
              ##Now scale x and y on this date wondow
              mutate(x = percent_rank(x), 
                     y = percent_rank(y)
              ) %>% 
              ##Get rid of the rest of the rows - leave only the row we are looking at
              filter(date == date(df[i,"date"])) 
      }
          return(x)
    }

    plan(multiprocess) # make sure to always include this in a run of the code.

    # Divide df evenly into three separate dataframes:
    df1 %<-% my_function(df[1:7, ], df1)
    df2 %<-% my_function(df = df[(8 - moving_window_days):14, ], df2) # But from here on out, go back 4 days to include that data in the moving average calculation.
    df3 %<-% my_function(df = df[(15 - moving_window_days):20, ], df3)

# See if your computer is able to split df into 4 or 5 separate dataframes. 

    # Now bind the dataframes together, but get the indexing right:
    rbind(df1, df2[(nrow(df2) - 6):nrow(df2), ], df3[(nrow(df3) - 5):nrow(df3), ])
```

Parallel processing is one of many ways to optimize code for efficiency. This exact technique has *substantially* sped up code for me in the past. It has reduced the run time of a program from a day and a half, down to 3 or 4 hours!

Now, ideally, we'd like to work with the apply family and matrices. This answer is just one of many ways we can speed up code. Also, the `future` package allows us to parallel process without learning a new looping structure, such as in the `parallel` package (which, nonetheless, is still an amazing package).

Also check out the `Rcpp` package. It'll take some time to learn, but is incredible for unlocking the speed of C++.

Answer (score 3):

`zoo::rollapply` can be quite fast.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = zoo::rollapply(x, width = 4, FUN = percent_rank, fill = "extend")[,1],
         y2 = zoo::rollapply(y, width = 4, FUN = percent_rank, fill = "extend")[,1])
```

Each call to `rollapply` generates a matrix with n=`width` columns. The first column is the value of the function for the window beginning with that observation, while the *n*th column is the value of the function for the window ending with that observation. You can change the `[,1]` to whichever column you want (the percentile in the middle of the window? at the end? at the beginning?).

The argument `fill = "extend"` duplicates the observations at the beginning or end of windows, since for the last *n-k* observations there are *k* missings from the window.

I expanded your dataset to a dummy of 28,496 rows, covering 26 names and 3 years of data, and ran this snippet with a width of 90 days. On my 4 year old desktop this took less than a minute for two variables:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  37.66    0.01   37.77
```

You could certainly use `purrr::map2` to iterate over 6 variables (instead of calling `rollapply` 6 times in `mutate`), but I'm not sure it would speed it up substantially.

Answer (score 0):

**@OP You should be CAUTIOUS with the answers provided**

**--My original answer--**

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I first `split` the data frame into a list of data frames grouped by `name`

```
split.df <- split(df, df$name)
```

Using the split data, use `lapply` and `map_df` to iterate over rows of each grouped df, `filter` for dates between relevant window of time using `between`, then `mutate` as you did before, and then `filter` for the relevant row again (I tried to 'copy' your code as closely as possible):

```
new <- lapply(split.df, function(z) map_df(1:nrow(z), ~z %>% 
                                              filter(between(date, z$date[.x]-moving_window_days, z$date[.x])) %>% 
                                              mutate(x=percent_rank(x),y=percent_rank(y)) %>% 
                                              filter(date==z$date[.x])))
```

This results in a `list`. To convert back to a single data frame

```
final <- Reduce("rbind",new)
```

Output (`head`)

```
   name       date         x    y
1     a 2017-01-01 0.0000000 0.00
2     a 2017-01-02 1.0000000 0.00
3     a 2017-01-03 1.0000000 0.50
4     a 2017-01-04 1.0000000 0.00
```

Let's make sure my result matches that of yours.

```
identical(final$x, OP.output$x)
[1] TRUE
```

**--END of my original answer--**

**----------------------------COMPARING SOLUTIONS----------------------------**

**--@Brian's answer--**
@Brian's answer does not give the same result you expect. You said your function `works as intended`, so let's compare Brian's result with yours. The first shows Brian's result. The second shows your result.

```
     name       date         x        y        x2        y2
 1      a 2017-01-01  6.044665 286.9410 0.0000000 1.0000000
 2      a 2017-01-02  8.070354 142.4285 0.0000000 1.0000000
 3      a 2017-01-03 11.884214 230.3348 0.3333333 0.3333333
 4      a 2017-01-04 18.255948 125.1110 0.3333333 1.0000000

   name       date         x    y
1     a 2017-01-01 0.0000000 0.00
2     a 2017-01-02 1.0000000 0.00
3     a 2017-01-03 1.0000000 0.50
4     a 2017-01-04 1.0000000 0.00

identical(Brian.output$x2, OP.output$x, )
[1] FALSE
```

**--END @Brian's answer--**

**--@Odysseus's answer--**

@Odysseus's answer returns the right result since it uses your same function, but you have to split the data frame manually. See his code below that calls `my_function`

```
df1 %<-% my_function(df[1:7, ], df1)
df2 %<-% my_function(df = df[(8 - moving_window_days):14, ], df2) # But from here on out, go back 4 days to include that data in the moving average calculation.
df3 %<-% my_function(df = df[(15 - moving_window_days):20, ], df3)
```

**--END @Odysseus's answer--**

You're likely to get the best gain in performance from @Odysseus answer, but you'll need to benchmark it yourself since it will depend on the number of cores you have. Parallelization is not always faster than a vectorized operation. But you'll need to extend his solution to the rest of your data frame.

Comment: You have to load the `lubridate` package to overcome the error.

Comment: Thanks. That did it